# my responsive design doesn't work on tablet/mobile

Tags: css, responsive

For week's now I can't figure out why my site is designed to be responsive, is everything right and laptop works perfectly even when put in a small size and then step into my mobile and is not responsive.

I've tried uninstalling the plugins, I changed the theme and not find out why.

Can you held me?

The website is: moinhodocomandante.com

Thanks for your atention,
Catarina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are intentionally trying to send your mobile users to dubious porn websites, my guess is that your site has been compromised. Lucky for you it has been poorly compromised and it is only breaking the page instead of displaying the ads/redirects.

To verify this, put your browser in developer mode and switch to mobile emulation and look at the network tab.

Without knowledge of your limitation, I cannot recommend any measures for cleaning up the compromise, but consider disabling every plugin and upgrading WP. It looks like every single call to a CSS file by your plugins gets redirected to something nefarious.

[image: Screen shot of network tab]

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not want to redirect to strange websites.
I've been to analyze and came from .htaccess files throughout the site and hidden in subfolders.

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: No problem. If my answer was helpful, please mark it as the correct answer. :)